# Is there a way to give specific features only to user in in-app purchase trial subscription in Flutter

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription, in-app-subscription

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to do this. I am building my flutter app it's going to have in app purchase subscription in in which I am offering a 3 days trial. I want to customise the 3 days trial in such way in which I can prevent the user to use those functionalities which are meant to be used by paid user's the one's who got real subscription, not using 3 days trial so is there's any way it is possible in flutter with the in app purchasing?

Once the 3 days trial runs out the app automatically will charge the person who took the trial, it is refundable for 3 days that's what the trial means but controlling features over in the trial phase is what I want.

Alternatively if its possible if user wants to access the restricted feature in the trial version If I can somehow run out the trial upon giving warning that if you want to access it'll run out your subscription and will cost you subscription so if even that is possible I'll be happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add one parameter like
 `featureType : Basic or Premium`
Now fetch the user's subscription plan information or save information in user's data.

So when user tap on specific feature you have to check condition either this feature belongs to premium plan or not. If yes than check user's subscription plan.